# Lang.Class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, gnome, gnome-shell-extensions

I'm trying to develop an Gnome Shell extension using GJS(Gnome Javascript), however, I came across the Lang library (I think it is a library, if not correct me). But I can't find any resources about it on the web.

In the code it looks something like this:

```
const Lang = imports.lang;

const ObjectA = new Lang.Class({ ... });
```

Where can I find some documentation about it? Is it a Gnome lib? A Mozilla lib?

Comment: FYI for future wanderers, `Lang` is deprecated now that we have native es6 classes, etc. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68369704/209050).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a built-in module of gjs -- see [modules/lang.js](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gjs/tree/modules/lang.js). It includes two main things: `bind()` (a helper to make "this" point to the logical object in closures) and `Class`, which basically implements a class in a language that does not have the concept of classes... It would be hard to work with GObject (a class-based object system) without this.