# how can I use "lang" in gjs?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gjs

I'm working on Gnome shell extension recently. I looked at some code, like this:

```
const Lang = imports.lang;

const extension = new Lang.Class({...}）
```

I can't find any information about Lang in GJS.

Where should I go to find the relevant development manual?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lang.Class in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497990/lang-class-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `Lang` anymore; it's deprecated and there are better ways. It was created before [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and [ES6 Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). Some reading:

- [GObject Basics](https://gjs.guide/guides/gobject/basics.html)
- [Legacy Class Syntax](https://gjs.guide/guides/gjs/legacy-class-syntax.html)
- [Migrating GNOME Shell Classes](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/MigratingShellClasses)

**Signal Callbacks**

```js
// NOTE: the emitting object is always the first argument,
//       so `this` is usually bound to a different object.
function myCallback(sourceObject, arg1) {
    if (this === sourceObject)
        log('`sourceObject` is correctly bound to `this`');
}

// OLD
sourceObject.connect('signal-name', Lang.bind(myCallback, sourceObject));

// NEW
sourceObject.connect('signal-name', myCallback.bind(sourceObject));
```

**GObject Classes**

```js
// OLD
const MyLegacyClass = new Lang.Class({
     GTypeName: 'MyLegacyClass',
     Extends: GObject.Object,
     _init(a, b) {
         this.parent(a);
         this.b = b;
     }
});

// NEW
const MyClass = GObject.registerClass({
     GTypeName: 'MyLegacyClass',
}, class MyClass extends GObject.Object { 
     _init(a, b) {
         super._init(a);
         this.b = b;
     }
);
```